# Can a ghost see through the Darkness spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, vision-and-light

The description of the Ghost says:

> ***Ethereal Sight.*** The ghost can see 60 feet into the Ethereal Plane when it is on the Material Plane, and vice versa.

And also:

> It is visible on the Material Plane while it is in the Border Ethereal, and vice versa.

Could that mean the Ghost can see through or rather on the other side of a *darkness* spell on the Material Plane?

Is **Ethereal Sight** described somewhere else?

I have found the following in DMG p. 48:

> From the Border Ethereal, a traveler can see into whatever plane it overlaps, but that plane appears muted and indistinct, its colors blurring into each other and its edges turning fuzzy. [...]

Which does not answer the question of: Can we see on the other side of a *darkness* spell (or even through it)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would rule "No", as p. 48 of the DMG states:

> Ethereal denizens watch the plane as through peering through distorted and frosted glass.

Using this analogy, the ghost will only see darkness, as it's only looking through a "glass", not some kind of special sense.

Think about it this way: Can a ghost on the Border Ethereal see through a wall on the Material Plane?

#### Ethereal Sight

I cannot find any other references to Ethereal Sight in the MM or the DMG. However, the Divination wizard's Third Eye feature (PHB, p. 117) does mention Ethereal Sight, but doesn't provide much clarity on the issue. The description of the *etherealness* spell mostly repeats the info from the DMG, but does imply that you can't see through objects (or other stuff), since you perceive everything in gray, not some sort of transparency.